# Cordova 5 whitelist, Content-Security-Policy and local network ip

Tags: javascript, cordova

I get this error when trying to load js files

> Refused to load the script 'http://192.168.1.10/js/test.js' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'

What policy should I use?

This is my meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

And the white list in config.xml (root)

```
<access origin="http://192.168.1.10/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.10/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://192.168.1.10/*" />
```

I'm building on platform cordova 5, android@4.0.2 and testing on Android 5.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, thought I'd post; I simply forgot to add the URL to the meta.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://192.168.1.10">
```